# Uncaught ReferenceError: pageTracker is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

You'll have to forgive me on this one. I understand that the issue is probably very simple, but I'm not a JS coder and am only just starting to get to grips with jQuery.

So I have a jQuery Ajax call in `$(document).ready`:

```
$('#newesttab').click(function() {

        $('li').removeClass('selectedtab');
        $('#newesttab').addClass('selectedtab');
        $('#col2').removeClass('featuredcol topratedcol').addClass('newestcol');

        $("#ajaxresults").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('code/newest'); ?>",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $('#ajaxresults').html(msg);
                    $("#ajaxresults").fadeIn("fast");
                    <?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost:8888') { ?>pageTracker._trackPageview('/code/newest/ajax');<?php } ?>
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

So basically when `#newesttab` is clicked, it does a bit of mumbo-jumbo with some Clases & IDs, fades stuff out, then loads some data from an Ajax CodeIgniter function. On success, the div `#ajaxresults` is filled with the data, fades in - and finally, you'll see this line:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost:8888') { ?>
   pageTracker._trackPageview('/code/newest/ajax');
<?php } ?>
```

All that does is check if I'm not on MAMP localhost so as to not get funky data in Analytics. If not, I call Google Analytic's `pageTracker` thingy to track the URL `code/newest/ajax` so it appears in my Analytics despite the page being called via Ajax. **That's correct, right?**

Well Chrome's console shows me this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pageTracker is not defined`

**The part I don't understand, is** that because this code is in `(document).ready` surely it should only fire when the entire document has loaded? And that means, therefore, that the Google Analytics Asynchronous snippet has loaded before my `</body>` tag (yep, it's definitely there)... I guess I'm misunerstanding something, right?

And before anybody asks, yes, I've tried this *not* on localhost ;)

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: Thought: is `pageTracker._trackPageView` not used in the new Asynchronous tracking code?

Comment: Is your tracking code (the piece that calls/loads ga.js) in <head> or <body>?

Comment: Cheers @doug , the tracking code is in `<body>` - before the closing `</body>` tag, as Google instructs. I thought though that the jQuery wouldn't fire until after that has been loaded though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was calling `pageTracker` when with the Async code you need to call `gaq_push`.

Comment: @Xeoncross: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503511/google-analytics-pagetracker-is-not-defined/3503587#3503587