# Google Analytics pageTracker is not defined?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Little bit confused... I am trying to track mailto links being clicked, but constantly 'pageTracker is not defined' is shown.  I have the following code just before my end body tag ()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-000000']); // This is my account number, I have added the zeros in this editor
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Then I am using this in my mailto links

```
<a href="mailto:hello@mydomain.co.uk" onClick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/mailto/hello');">hello@mydomain.co.uk</a>
```

I cannot see why its not working?  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The new Async Google Analytics code (that you're using) works a bit differently than the non-Async. Any time that you want to call a method on pageTracker you simply push a "message" onto the "_gaq" queue.

```
<a href="mailto:hello@mydomain.co.uk" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/mailto/hello'])">hello@mydomain.co.uk</a>
```

Although, tracking a mailto link may work better as an event:

```
<a href="mailto:hello@mydomain.co.uk" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mailto', 'home'])">hello@mydomain.co.uk</a>
```

For more info take a look at the [Async Tracking Users Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html).

Comment: Awesome thanks :)  Love this place, a few minutes and the answer - Posted hours ago on the Google forum and not one reply!

Comment: I think OP got tripped up on the same thing as I did. to wit: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55529 <-- this answer from google is misleading IMO and makes your code plotz as described above.

Answer (score 20):

We can also add:

```
//mantain syntax between old and new asynch methods
//http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#Syntax
function _pageTracker (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this._trackEvent = function(a,b,c) {
       _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', a, b, c]);
    };
}

var pageTracker = new _pageTracker();
```

in new code to mantain old code in pages.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code :

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'pdf', 'download', '/pdf/myPdf'])">myPdf</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed a way to tack downloading PDFs too and heres what I used:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/assets/downloads/filename.pdf" target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Download', 'Price Brochure PDF'])">Download Brochure</a>
```

For more info about **_trackEvent**, heres the [API Doc page](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)